# Stream video from Xbox Kinect over network

Tags: c#, networking, compression, kinect, tcpclient

I am trying to stream a video from an Xbox Kinect over LAN. I wrote a socket class that will send at about 25 mega bits per second with a good connection and about 1 mega bit per second with a bad connection. This will be on a robot so I will shoot for 1Mbps and I would like to get 15 FPS with minimal lag. Getting the YUV format from the camera (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj131027.aspx) it needs 4 bits per pixel. I will cut the resolution to 320 x 240. So let me do the math for a frame (320 * 240 * 4 / 1024 / 1024) = 0.29296875 Mbs which means I can stream at 3.4 FPS if I'm can only send at 1Mbps. So I need to reduce the byte array to about a fifth of the size. I've looked into this before but it actually takes longer to compress the byte array, send it and then decompress the array than it does to just send the raw data. Is there a good algorithm that's fast enough to do this?

Comment: The entire question talks about how fast I need it to go, that's why I did the math.

Comment: Yeah, but so much depends on the amount of processing available. All there is to go on here is that some unknown compression algorithm compresses x amount of data in an unknown amount of time. It's difficult to understand the constraints of the problem without more info.

Answer (score 3):

Aren't they called video codecs?

You'll be missing out if you don't treat the data as video... it's much more compressible than raw data. There are many codecs around for all sorts of applications. The choice is usually a compromise between processing cost and bandwidth. It all depends on how much heavy lifting your robot can do before booting the data over the network.